# Apk file download issue in android default browser

Tags: android, servlets, apk

I am trying to download an .apk file from android default browser using https connection and through servlet on sumbit button click to secure it but its not getting download

```
Exception :org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

the same thing is working fine in firefox browser in mobile and in PC too and when i remove the https or ssl certificate it will start to work with default also but i need it with https connection only so please help me regarding this.I did a research work on that and find the error in android default browser log:

```
V/SecDownloader(5049): CDHelpers : chooseExtensionFromMimeType: couldn't find    
extensionm using CDContentType map for application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

i have also tried with different extensions but not even a text file is downloading .
please help.

Comment: Do you supply a MIME type in your http response?

Comment: I am writing these in header response.setContentType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                   + request.getParameter("file").toUpperCase()+"\"");

Comment: @Rorchackh did u get the problem please reply its very urgent.

Comment: Sorry man, I have no idea what is causing this issue, but you may want to checkout this page http://balusc.blogspot.dk/2007/07/fileservlet.html it does not necessarily answer you question directly but it may make sending files back to browsers work in all of them.

Comment: check i have edited the question after my research work.

Comment: are both the Android browser and firefox on the same phone? is it a phone or emulator?

Comment: ya they both on the same phone galaxy s2

Comment: i got the exact prob is because of https connection if remove the ssl certificate its working so could you please help how to make it possible with ssl.

Comment: I really don't know man. Maybe this is a bug in the Android browser (since it's working in Firefox), you should force a non encrypted connection when downloading the APK file

Comment: @Rorchackh could you please tell me how can we  force a non encrypted connection only for downloading the file while the whole site is SSL certificate enabled .Thanks alot :)

Comment: You could have the href attribute of the anchor tag pointing to the APK file start with http://

Comment: Are you downloading through https?

Comment: yes, it did not worked so I have given direct link of apk file on device instead of going through servlet. I know this is not a secure way but did not find any solution. My research work concluded that the problem is because of default browser passes the request of file download to Download manager and there is no permanent exception adding in default browser so while passing the request download manager rejecting the request because of unsecure connection. Its my theory not sure.